# Reading PHP Cookie is Impossible

Tags: php, cookies, php-7.0

I tried to read a PHP cookie but I couldn't, although I was able to see it in the Chrome console. I have found the solution myself, using debugging methods, but in case someone else is having the same problem, I'll answer this question myself, in order to save you time.

I was using this code:

```
if(!empty($_COOKIE['my.cookie'])) {
    echo "cookie value: ".$_COOKIE['my.cookie'];
}
// fallback
else {
    echo "cookie not set!";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the var_dump() function helped me identify the problem, because the cookie-name was changed by PHP, automatically. (Maybe a bug, or some kind of known limit - my version is PHP 7.0.33.)

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

This resulted in the list of cookies printed on the web page, and the cookie name was changed from "my.page-LANG" to "my_page-LANG".

So I renamed my cookie and I was good:

```
if(!empty($_COOKIE['my_cookie'])) {
    echo "cookie value: ".$_COOKIE['my_cookie'];
}
// fallback
else {
    echo "cookie not set!";
}
```

Comment: This is cleary documented: https://www.php.net/variables.external#language.variables.external.dot-in-names

Comment: Plus without validating the cookie value in any way, this could possibly enable path traversal attacks.

Comment: But website language switching should not be handled via a cookie in the first place - search engines bots etc. usually don’t accept cookies, so your different language content would probably not even be properly index-able. The language is information that belongs into the URL, not cookies.

Comment: @Daan: How do I know that a cookie name is equal to a variable name? That's not documented on your linked page. Otherwise I'd immediately agree.

Comment: @Dharman: I'm not a PHP expert, I took that "echo var_dump" snippet from another SO answer. I have improved/tested and edited the sample!

Comment: @Dharman: My bad - I found the post, but it was good. I must have added the "echo" in mental derangement ;-) sorry. This happens sometimes, when I'm trying to sort unknown things.

Comment: @04FS: I have generalized my post. It doesn't matter what kind of cookie it is, the actual problem remains the same in all cases.

Comment: @04FS: It's an internal application, no indexing required.